# Get specific dict in Python

Tags: python, json

I've this JSON file (it's a little part of the file):

```
[
   {
      "History bleed": {
         "sentences": [
            {
               "words": [
                  [
                     "History",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "7",
                        "Lemma": "history",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"
                     }
                  ],
                  [
                     "bleed",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "VB",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "39",
                        "Lemma": "bleed",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "34"
                     }
                  ]
               ],
               "indexeddependencies": [],
               "parsetree": [],
               "text": "History of lower gastrointestinal bleed",
               "dependencies": []
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "Antigen of Bordetella": {
         "sentences": [
            {
               "words": [
                  [
                     "Antigen",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "7",
                        "Lemma": "antigen",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"
                     }
                  ],
                  [
                     "of",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "IN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "10",
                        "Lemma": "of",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "8"
                     }
                  ],
                  [
                     "Bordetella",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "21",
                        "Lemma": "bordetellum",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "PERSON",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "11"
                     }
                  ]
               ],
               "indexeddependencies": [],
               "parsetree": [],
               "text": "Antigen of Bordetella",
               "dependencies": []
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "Anti-Histoplasma": {
         "sentences": [
            {
               "words": [
                  [
                     "Anti-Histoplasma",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "JJ",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "16",
                        "Lemma": "anti-histoplasma",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"
                     }
                  ],
               ],
               "indexeddependencies": [],
               "parsetree": [],
               "text": "Anti-Histoplasma capsulatum IgG",
               "dependencies": []
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

and I want to get this:

```
{
         "sentences": [
            {
               "words": [
                  [
                     "Antigen",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "7",
                        "Lemma": "antigen",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"
                     }
                  ],
                  [
                     "of",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "IN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "10",
                        "Lemma": "of",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "8"
                     }
                  ],
                  [
                     "Bordetella",
                     {
                        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
                        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "21",
                        "Lemma": "bordetellum",
                        "NamedEntityTag": "PERSON",
                        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "11"
                     }
                  ]
               ],
               "indexeddependencies": [],
               "parsetree": [],
               "text": "Antigen of Bordetella",
               "dependencies": []
            }
         ]
      }
```

To obtain that I write this:

```
    with open(pathOfTheJsonFIle) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    print(data['Antigen of Bordetella'])
```

but i get this error: *list indices must be integers, not str*

This file is quite big (there are more than 10.000 items) so I would like to find the item *Antigen of Bordetella* using some index (and not writing data[2], for example)

Comment: The type of data flowing in from the JSON file is a `list` and not a `JSON` as you are expecting it to be. You can use it like this:  `print(data[0]['Antigen of Bordetella'])` for getting the lists 1st index json values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the JSON file starts with a list and not a dictionary.

Try:

```
for i in data:
    if 'Antigen of Bordetella' in i:
        print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) you could do this:

```
from itertools import ifilter
...
searchkey = "Antigen of Bordetella"
search_data = ifilter(lambda X: searchkey in X, data).next()[searchkey]
```